# Regions In Transition в java application

Tags: java, hbase

Please tell me what's wrong, I'm new to working with hbase. when creating regions in a java application for hbase, an error occurs below then.

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.DoNotRetryRegionException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.DoNotRetryRegionException: bc3ec95b447809887e3c198afe4d1084 is not OPEN; regionState={bc3ec95b447809887e3c198afe4d1084 state=CLOSING, ts=1651224527248, server=hbase-docker,16020,1651207907804}
```

Code as below:

```
byte[][] splits = getSplits(countSplits, countSlot);
        for (byte[] byteSplit : splits) {
            byte[] regionName = admin.getRegions(tableName).get(admin.getRegions(tableName).size() - 1).getRegionName();
            admin.splitRegionAsync(regionName, byteSplit);
        }
```

This code is executed and 1 region out of 20 required is created. After creating the first one, the error above occurs. What needs to be added? I hope for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding a waiting time between operations.

```
.....
admin.splitRegionAsync(regionName, byteSplit);
Thread.sleep(30000);
.....
```